# ADB shell command inconsistency with 'and' operator on latest android sdk

Tags: shell, adb

I am trying to fetch precise native contact information for which we used adb shell command such as

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/ --projection id --where "deleted='0' and id='72054'"
```

We got below error while running on another system with same android sdk configuration.

-Result

> [Error] Unsupported argument: and

How do I fix this? I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong by the error.

**Note:** I have checked adb version on both the systems which is same -
*Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32*

Answer (score 2):

I just fiddled around for hours to solve the same problem. What eventually worked for me was escaping the whitespaces around the "and" and quoting / quote-escaping slightly differently. Applied to your where clause this would result in

```
--where 'deleted=\"0\"\ AND\ id=\"72054\"'
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me